# Global Variable for Asynchronous data access in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a below controller

```
@Controller
public class TestController{

public Future<ArrayList<String>> global_value = null;

@Autowired
private AsyncService asyncService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/asyncCall", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getToken(HttpServletRequest request) {

   global_value = asyncService.execute();

return "OK";

}

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getAsyncData", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ArrayList<String> getData() {
    try {
            if (global_value != null && global_value.get().size() > 0) {

                return global_value.get();

            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
return null;
}

}
```

When I long poll the `getAsncData` endpoint, how do I maintain the global_value is just for a request. global_value must be unique for the request scope.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you want global_value in request scope, then don't make it an instance variable.

Comment: You meant to define as static?